# Apps Android Híbridas. A perda de performance é tão grande assim?

Tags: java, android, aplicação-web

Alguém aí já desenvolveu apps híbridas para Android e sabe me dizer se a perda de performance é grande? Já li em artigos diversos nessa web afora que acontecem problemas como atraso no evento de touch, eventuais lentidões, etc. Se puderem compartilhar experiências ou mesmo deixar links de referência, será de grande ajuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso depende. A resposta pode ser sim, há redução de performance significativa, ou  ou não, não faz diferença.

**Situações aonde uma App Hibrida tem performance semelhante ao app padrão**

- Equivalente em app nativa também precisar acessar internet para funcionar, e a app hibrida não fazer download de muito mais conteúdo que a nativa
- Apps comuns e sem nenhuma complexidade adicional

**Situações aonde uma App Hibrida tende a ter performance perceptivelmente pior**

- Jogos e aplicativos que trabalhem com gráficos intensos

Comment: Mo meu caso, é apenas conexão a um webservice para montar a view com os dados vindos de lá.

Answer (score 2):

Em alguns casos o problema de lentidão acontece porque as aplicações híbridas rodam em cima de uma camada nativa (webview). Logo, ao invés de ter um acesso direto, o app faz uma emulação pra rodar.

No seu caso, não vejo grandes perdas de performance já que é um acesso a um webservice. Cuidado apenas com o número de requisições. Já desenvolvi apps com este tipo de comunicação e não tive problemas com performance.